# Spring cannot use AOP with embedded database scripts

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-data

Spring cannot initialize the bean "dataSource", while the bean declaration contains the `<jdbc:script location="...."/>`
line, when I am running my unit test.

The path to the script seems to be correct, the script seems to be correct.

The initialization goes this way: applicationContext.xml imports db-h2-config.xml, where it finds the "dataSource" bean.

If this bean contains any of the `<jdbc:script location>` part, then it fails with the attached stacktrace. (For the full stacktrace please see below)

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3427b02d': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#41fbdac4' of type [org.springframework.jdbc.config.SortedResourcesFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'scripts'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#41fbdac4': Post-processing of FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is java.lang.AssertionError
```

If I remove the `<jdbc:script location>` part, there is no error.

**UPDATE:**
I have added SayAOP.java and TrackCoach.java code below.

SayAOP.java:

```
package hu.springdemo;

public class SayAOP {

   public void shoutAOPBefore() {
        System.out.println("HERE IS THE AOP BEFORE");
    }

    public void shoutAOPAfter(){
        System.out.println("HERE IS THE AOP After");
    }
}
```

TrackCoach.java:

```
package hu.springdemo;

public class TrackCoach implements CoachIF {
    @Override
    public void getDailyWorkout() {
        System.out.println("TrackCoach says: 'Go and run 5k!' ");
    }
```

}

AppTest.java:

```
package hu.apptest;

import hu.springdemo.BaseballAthlete;
import hu.springdemo.CoachIF;
import hu.springdemo.CoachSpringConfig;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.Location;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/applicationContext.xml")
public class AppTest {

    @Autowired
    CoachIF myBaseBallGuy;

    @Test
    public void baseballAthleteShouldNotBeNull() {
        assertNotNull(myBaseBallGuy);
        myBaseBallGuy.getDailyWorkout();
    }
}
```

db-h2-config.xml:

```
<beans xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd">

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
            <jdbc:script location="classpath:db/sql/create-db.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd
">

    <import resource="classpath:db-h2-config.xml"/>

    <bean id="myTrackCoach"
          class="hu.springdemo.TrackCoach">
    </bean>

    <bean id="SayAOP"
          class="hu.springdemo.SayAOP">
    </bean>

    <aop:config>

        <aop:aspect id="mtc" ref="SayAOP">
            <aop:pointcut id="pmtc" expression="execution(* hu.springdemo.TrackCoach.getDailyWorkout(..))"/>
            <aop:before pointcut-ref="pmtc" method="shoutAOPBefore"/>
            <aop:after pointcut-ref="pmtc" method="shoutAOPAfter"/>
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>

</beans>
```

create-db.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30),
  email  VARCHAR(50)
);
```

stacktrace:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:253)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#72f926e6' of type [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CompositeDatabasePopulator] while setting bean property 'databasePopulator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#72f926e6': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3427b02d' of type [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator] while setting bean property 'populators' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3427b02d': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#41fbdac4' of type [org.springframework.jdbc.config.SortedResourcesFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'scripts'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#41fbdac4': Post-processing of FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#72f926e6': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3427b02d' of type [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator] while setting bean property 'populators' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3427b02d': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#41fbdac4' of type [org.springframework.jdbc.config.SortedResourcesFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'scripts'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#41fbdac4': Post-processing of FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3427b02d': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#41fbdac4' of type [org.springframework.jdbc.config.SortedResourcesFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'scripts'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#41fbdac4': Post-processing of FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#41fbdac4': Post-processing of FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:302)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.aspectj.weaver.UnresolvedType.nameToSignature(UnresolvedType.java:726)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.UnresolvedType.forName(UnresolvedType.java:231)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:423)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.couldMatchJoinPointsInType(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.matches(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:250)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:220)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:279)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:311)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:347)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1723)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:130)
    ... 62 more


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: seems to be a failure related to AOP config. Please update the question with code for hu.springdemo.SayAOP and hu.springdemo.TrackCoach

Comment: I have added them, but I doubt that it is related to the AOP by looking at the stacktrace, and since  the whole code with the AOP works fine when the <jdbc:script location="classpath:db/sql/create-db.sql"/> removed.

Comment: Out of curiosity I simulated your project. Everything checkout fine. Please check the code here and let me know what is the difference https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1HIbVHFF10cMTBYUFpvd0dwT28/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thsnk you Abdul! May I ask you to post your solution as an answer with explicitly writing your code there, not as an attachment? I can accept it if it works, also it may help others later.

Comment: The problem was indeed related to Spring AOP!

Comment: sure will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with AspectJ. Please upgrade the aspectj dependency to the latest version. Please check the JIRA's for more details

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9272

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7989

Answer (score 0):

Different problem but it's solution is solved my issue as well, however the causes are still not clear, seems that somehow the running of my scripts has clashed with the Spring AOP:

[Populating H2 database with Spring and jdbc DataSourceTransactionManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403336/populating-h2-database-with-spring-and-jdbc-datasourcetransactionmanager)

I changed embedded database bean as follows to remove script elements:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="embeddedH2Database" type="H2"/>
```

And added @Sql annotation before my test to create table and load table.

```
@Sql({"classpath:db/sql/create-db.sql", "classpath:db/sql/insert-data.sql"})
```